# Flutter BLoC: listen callback called multiple times

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc, flutter-plugin, flutter-packages

my blocConsumer listener calling muliple time i dont know why?

This is my auth cubit page

```
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

import '../../../ApiManager/api_manager.dart';
import 'auth_state.dart';

class AuthCubit extends Cubit<AuthState> {
ApiManager _apiManager = ApiManager();
  AuthCubit() : super(AuthInitialState()){
    // User? currentUser = _auth.currentUser;
    // if(currentUser != null){
    //   //logged in
    //   emit(AuthLoggedInState(currentUser));
    // }else{
    //   //logged out
    //   emit(AuthLoggedOutState());
    // }
  }
  void sentOTP(String phoneNum) async {
    emit(AuthLoadingState());
    await _apiManager.sentOTPApi(phoneNum).then((val){
      print("sentOTPApi:: $val");
      emit(AuthLoadingOffState());
      if(val["StatusCode"] == 200){
        emit(AuthCodeSentState(""));
      }

    });
  }

  void verifyOTP(String phoneNum,String otp) async {
    print("verifyOTP22");
    emit(AuthLoadingState());
    await _apiManager.verifyOTPApi(phoneNum,otp).then((val){
      print("verifyOTPApi:: $val");
      emit(AuthLoadingOffState());
      if(val["StatusCode"] == 200){
        emit(AuthCodeSentState(val["ResponsePacket"]));
      }
    });
    }
}
```

this is my otp verify page,

### on click submit listener calling multiple times.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:pin_code_fields/pin_code_fields.dart';
import '../BlocPages/CubitPage/AuthCubit/auth_cubit.dart';
import '../BlocPages/CubitPage/AuthCubit/auth_state.dart';
import '../BlocPages/InternetCubit/internet_cubit.dart';
import '../Components/loader.dart';
import '../Utils/ConstantsPages/toast_page.dart';
import '../Utils/GlobalColor/global_color.dart';
import '../Utils/GlobalTextStyles/global_text_styles.dart';
import '../Utils/GlobalWidgetPages/full_width_btn_with_filled_color.dart';
import '../Utils/GlobalWidgetPages/pin_code_field.dart';
import '../Utils/GlobalWidgetPages/top_bg_image_with_back_button.dart';
import 'create_profile_page.dart';

class EnterOTPPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final phoneNum;

  const EnterOTPPage({Key? key, this.phoneNum}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<EnterOTPPage> createState() => _EnterOTPPageState();
}

class _EnterOTPPageState extends State<EnterOTPPage> {
  TextEditingController otpController = TextEditingController();
  ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
  StreamController<ErrorAnimationType>? errorController;
  FocusNode myFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  Timer? _timer;
  int _start = 60;
  bool visible = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    errorController = StreamController<ErrorAnimationType>();
    startTimer();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    errorController!.close();
    _timer!.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        height: size.height,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: MyColor.whiteColor,
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('assets/bg_image.png'),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            )),
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            controller: scrollController,
            physics: ScrollPhysics(),
            child: BlocBuilder<InternetCubit, InternetState>(
                builder: (context, internetState) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  BGImageWithButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 44),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
                            child: Text(
                              "Verify OTP",
                              style: textStyleWith24600(MyColor.blackColor),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding:
                                EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, left: 20, right: 20),
                            child: RichText(
                              maxLines: 2,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              text: TextSpan(
                                  text: "You've received an OTP at ",
                                  style:
                                      textStyleWith12400(MyColor.darkGreyColor),
                                  children: <TextSpan>[
                                    TextSpan(
                                      text: "${widget.phoneNum}",
                                      style: textStyleWith12600(
                                          MyColor.darkGreyColor),
                                    ),
                                    TextSpan(
                                      text: " Change",
                                      style:
                                          textStyleWith12600(MyColor.blueColor),
                                      recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                                        ..onTap = () {
                                          print(
                                              "click on mobile number change");
                                          Navigator.pop(context);
                                        },
                                    ),
                                  ]),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: 35.0, left: 20, right: 20),
                              child: PinCodeFieldPage(
                                length: 6,
                                controller: otpController,
                                errorController: errorController!,
                              )),
                          Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12.0),
                              child: Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      vertical: 0, horizontal: 20),
     // here this 
     // BlocConsumerlistener calling 
     //multiple times                             
                                            child: BlocConsumer<AuthCubit, 
                                   AuthState>(
                                      listener: (context, authState) {
                                        if (authState is AuthLoadingState) {
                                          return showLoader(context);
                                        } else if (authState is AuthCodeSentState) {
                                          print("went another page");
                                          Navigator.push(
                                              context,
                                              (MaterialPageRoute(
                                                  builder: (context) =>
                                                      CreateProfilePage())));
                                        } else if (authState
                                        is AuthLoadingOffState) {
                                          print("hideLoader");
                                          return hideLoader(context);
                                        }
                                      }, builder: (context, authState) {
                                    return FullWidthBtnWithFilledColor(
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        if (internetState ==
                                            InternetState.Gained) {
                                          continueToVerify();
                                        } else if (internetState ==
                                            InternetState.Lost) {
                                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                              .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                                            content: Text(
                                                "Internet is not Connected!"),
                                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                                          ));
                                        }
                                      },
                                      btnColor: MyColor.primaryRedColor,
                                      btnText: "SUBMIT",
                                      btnTextColor: MyColor.whiteColor,
                                    );
                                  }))),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: size.height > 680.0
                                    ? size.height * 0.2
                                    : size.height * 0.11,
                                left: 20,
                                right: 20),
                            child: RichText(
                              maxLines: 1,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              text: TextSpan(
                                  text: "Resend OTP in ",
                                  style:
                                      textStyleWith12400(MyColor.darkGreyColor),
                                  children: <TextSpan>[
                                    TextSpan(
                                      text: "$_start",
                                      style:
                                          textStyleWith12400(MyColor.blueColor),
                                    ),
                                    TextSpan(
                                      text: " s",
                                      style: textStyleWith12400(
                                          MyColor.darkGreyColor),
                                    ),
                                  ]),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

extension ActionMethod on _EnterOTPPageState {
  void startTimer() {
    const oneSec = const Duration(seconds: 1);
    _timer = new Timer.periodic(
      oneSec,
      (Timer timer) {
        if (_start == 0) {
          setState(() {
            timer.cancel();
            visible = true;
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            _start--;
          });
        }
      },
    );
  }

  recendOTP() {
    setState(() {
      _start = 30;
      startTimer();
      visible = false;
    });
    print("resend otp");
  }

  continueToVerify() {
    bool isValidateNO = validateOTPNumber(otpController);

    if (isValidateNO) {
      BlocProvider.of<AuthCubit>(context)
          .verifyOTP(widget.phoneNum, otpController.text);
    }
  }

  bool validateOTPNumber(TextEditingController controller) {
    if (controller.value.text.length < 6) {
      showToastWithColor("Please enter your otp", MyColor.blackColor);
      debugPrint(controller.value.text);
      return false;
    } else {
      debugPrint(controller.value.text);
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i see alot of over engineering going on in your code. try not to do that. Im talking about the extension part, also move your blocConsumer above the SafeArea

Comment: its not working , till now listener calling multiple times

Comment: do you have anydesk?

Comment: yes  i have can we connect??

Comment: with same code of blocConsumer listener of enter mobile number page , its working fine after mobile number page i am redirecting on otp verify page then here issue is coming

Comment: send me link,or whatsapp +233278805288